# Different design for two targets in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have two targets for my project. Each of them have different images for UI elements. ( only colors for images are different. Sizes are the same ). Views for first target are already created. I am looking a way for redesigning app for second target. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to have the two separate sets of resources in separate folders added to your project, with the same filenames. Then just make sure that the one set is added only to your first target, and the second set is added only to the second target. You'll find the checkbox for "target membership" on the right hand side of the screen when you have an image selected. This way each target will only have the images it needs, instead of both having both sets of images. Then you also don't need separate storyboards.

Comment: Thank you @Gavin. It sounds great. I was thinking about this but wanted to be sure. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, what you can do is create a different storyboard then assign each one to the appropriate target.

Under General tab, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer @meda. Well i know about this solution. The point is I need to create 2 storyboards ( iPhone and iPad ) again. I know also that can create IBOutlets and change images programmatically. I am wondering is there another solution for doing this using one storyboard.

Comment: @Gago you can check out my answer, it should allow you to have separate images without separate storyboards.